# Failed to parse: comment: 1. \'comment\' field must be of BSON type string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript

I m using mongodb native drive to get the cursor of a query result.
 I m using a 'comment' field which is basically a string below is the code snippet i m using

```
let leve1_n = 'labreports';
let matchLabReports = { level1_n: "labreports" };
let sortCondition = { _id: 1 };
let projection = {comment : 1 , color: 1, value: 1, value_n: 1, value_d: 1, rangeStart: 1, rangeEnd: 1, level2: 1 };
let collectionName = collectionNames.biomarkerAggregations;
let cursor = dbModule.findCursorSort(dbModule.getDbHandle(dbName), collectionName, matchLabReports, projection,sortCondition);

        cursor.forEach(doc => {    
        // Lambda Expression
        // Do something with doc.
        })
```

**findcursorSort**

```
function findCursorSort(db, collectionName, query, projection, sortCondition, options) {
    if (!errorCheck(db)) {
        let cursor = db.collection(collectionName).find(query, projection).sort(sortCondition);
        if (!options) {
            return cursor;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            cursor = cursor.addOption(options[i]);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

but this is giving me error like..

> name: 'MongoError',
>     message: 'Failed to parse: comment: 1. \'comment\' field must be of BSON type string.',
>     ok: 0,
>     errmsg: 'Failed to parse: comment: 1. \'comment\' field must be of BSON type string.',
>     code: 9,
>     codeName: 'FailedToParse' }

After removing comment field from the project everything is working fine.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `.findCursorSort()` is a custom function in your code. What does it do? We need to know because the error is coming from code "inside" that function.

Comment: Unrelated ( I think ) but I'm also guessing that with this `let leve1_n = 'labreports';
let matchLabReports = { level1_n: "labreports" };` you actually mean `let leve1_n = 'labreports'; let matchLabReports = { }; matchLabReports[level1_n] = "labreports";` which is actually how you would assign a dynamic key to the query. Your code will be stringified to `{ "level1_n": "labreports" }` despite that you might think you were using the varaible value. You were not, since that is not how key names in JavaScript objects work.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for ur kind reply. Yes  .findCursorSort() is a custom function here is the code for this function.  https://jsfiddle.net/jjv0g6k0/

Comment: Please do not try and paste code in comments. The [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44255786/edit) link on your question is for adding details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an feature in collection.js in mongodb native driver, to check which fields are options of query and which are projection. All fields from projection will be as options if they consist of some fields like comment, limit, sort etc. (written in testForFields variable).

Try to fix this issue like so:

original code:

```
db.collection(collectionName).find(query, projection)
```

fixed code:

```
db.collection(collectionName).find(query).project(projection)
```

It helped me to solve problem.